# Where the API Token should be put in standard form? Header or URI?

Tags: asp.net, api, security, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing an API using ASP.Net WebAPI, and authorizing clients with an access token. I want to know which source is more standard to put the access token? Headers, Uri or Body?
For example in Instagram API, clients should pass access token in uri as a query string. But I think in Twitter API the request must include an Authorization header.

Let me know if there is an standard rule.

Comment: Header is much more secure.

Comment: @RezaOwliaei How? Give me a reason!

Comment: Check it out: http://geekolator.com/2013/03/30/custom-headers-vs-query-string/

Comment: using GET for sensitive data is a bad idea for several reasons:

Mostly HTTP referrer leakage (an external image in the target page might leak the password)
Password will be stored in server logs (which is obviously bad)
History caches in browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security related information such as an API Token go in the `Authorization` header.  That is what it is designed for.

Putting api keys in the URI increases the chances of the API keys getting stored in the log file and it makes public caching far less effective.

Comment: I don't understand the second part of your answer. Would you please give me more explanation?

Comment: @RezaAhmadi Adding an API key to the URI changes the resource identifier.  This means that if you try and cache that representation then you  may get a copy of the representation in the cache for each API key.  Some caches choose to ignore the query string, but others do not.